# Protocol for Web Description Resources

Tags: semantic-web, powder

Is POWDER (http://www.w3.org/TR/powder-dr/) meant to be used for Trust/ Proof layers of the Semantic Web? Are there any other w3c standards made for the same layers?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the upper layers are pretty much still science fiction, and no one knows whether they will work out exactly in the way suggested by the usual [layer cake diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web_Stack).

There are some standards that might be useful as building blocks for supporting these higher layers. POWDER is one of them. Named Graphs (as standardised in SPARQL, and currently under consideration as a native feature of RDF 1.1) is another one. The [W3C Provenance Ontology](http://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/) is yet another one.

Then there's plenty of proposals and research ideas that are not yet ready for standardisation.

Comment: Hi Richard, can I quote you on "the upper layers are pretty much still science fiction"? By the way, I fully agree... indeed there is more fiction than science up there! ;-)